# playing one off the other

Tags: prepositions

> Countries like Bulgaria have spent decades balancing East and West,
>   and **playing one off the other**. But the prospect of President Trump’s
>   moving closer to Mr. Putin has scrambled that strategy, as have the
>   conflicting messages coming out of the new American administration.

[Bulgaria Grows Uneasy as Trump Complicates Its Ties to Russia](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/04/world/europe/bulgaria-trump-russia-putin.html?&version=readinglist&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=c-column-middle-span-region&region=c-column-middle-span-region&WT.nav=c-column-middle-span-region)
the New York Times

Shouldn't this be: *play sb off **against** sb*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the *off the other* portion, only,  of the expression playing one *off the other*:

Countries have spent decades ... not *playing off* anyone, so much as playing A *off* (resulting from) how they are playing B, and vice versa.

In your example, once the West (US) takes the same position as the East (Russia), countries like Bulgaria can no longer take advantage of the competition. When East = West, there is no *playing them off the other*.

If I have two buyers for a house, I am playing them off each other when I tell each of the rising purchase bids that the other made -- thus I keep raising the bids, one *off the other*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be 'playing one off against the other' because this gives the most accurate meaning that Bulgaria was using the conflicting stances of the East and the West for her own benefit.

Comment: mr chris ,can you please give more explanation on that.

Comment: Yes, 'to play off' is a sports term meaning to settle a match, whereas 'to play off  X against  Y'  is the phrase you should use in this context. 1.Sports
a. To establish the winner of (a tie) by playing in an additional game or series of games.
b. To participate in a playoff.
2. PoliticsTo set (one individual or party) in opposition to another so as to advance one's own interests: a parent who played off one child against another.

Answer (score 0):

The Ngram viewer finds *play off against* more popular in print (insert caveats here) by twenty to one, but the phrase missing the *off* may still be found, as in this definitional passage from [*Gurus, Hired Guns, and Warm Bodies: Itinerant Experts in a Knowledge Economy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nWWAGnBDzJEC&pg=PT121&dq=%22play%20one%20off%20the%20other%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4h9Our4DSAhWl5oMKHeN4DIcQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22play%20one%20off%20the%20other%22&f=false) by S R Barley and G Kunda:

> But as the sociologist Georg Simmel argued nearly a hundred years ago, in a triad the one who can best control the flow of information between the other two or **play one off the other** becomes the *tertius gaudens*, the “third who benefits."

The popularity seems reversed using the general google.